# Events not showing by id from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a list of buttons and each one is related to a person. When you click on a button, it goes to `calendar.php?id=5` (id of the personnal)

I would like it shows his/her calendar with the vacations registered to his/her id from mysql database.

`events.php` report properly the events from my database but the calendar stays empty. How can I make it works please ?

Currently it gets events like this: 
(calendar.php)

```
<?php
$getid = $_GET['id'];
//echo $getid;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            editable: false,
            allDayDefault: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: "http://localhost/planning/events.php?id='$getid'"

        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

(events.php)

```
<?php

$getid = $_GET['id'];

$json = array();

$requete = "SELECT id,title,start,end FROM absence WHERE id='$getid'";
$resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

The response from events.php seems good. It shows this for id 37 as exemple :

(http://localhost/planning/events.php?id=37)

```js
[{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2013-05-10 00:00:00","end":"2013-05-10 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2013-07-22 00:00:00","end":"2013-08-11 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2013-12-19 00:00:00","end":"2014-01-07 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2012-07-30 00:00:00","end":"2012-08-09 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2012-05-11 00:00:00","end":"2012-05-13 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2014-08-11 00:00:00","end":"2014-08-24 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2014-11-10 00:00:00","end":"2014-11-16 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2014-06-10 00:00:00","end":"2014-06-11 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE PAYE","start":"2014-12-24 00:00:00","end":"2015-01-11 00:00:00"},{"id":"37","title":"CONGE SANS SOLDE","start":"2012-08-10 00:00:00","end":"2012-08-15 00:00:00"}]
```

Sadly the calendar stays empty.

Comment: You need to check the response from `events.php`. Do you have a valid json object? Does that object have the events you're trying to show?

Comment: milz thank you for your reply. I've edited my first post and i'm showing the result of events.php. All seems correct but the calendar stays empty

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to be sure:

1. Your date in the calendar must match the date from your events.
2. You need to set `allDay` (see the [Event Object docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)) for events that don't have time. Alternatively, you can set [`allDayDefault`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/).

For demonstration purposes, check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/fhkk20fa/). I've used the json from your update. Here are my changes:

1. Added `defaultDate: '2013-05-10',` in order to see one event (the first from the json object)
2. Added `allDay: true` to the event on 2013-05-10.
3. Added `allDay: true` to the event that occurs between 2013-07-22 and 2013-08-11

---

Update

Based on your comments you have an issue with your query. Change this:

```
$requete = "SELECT id,title,start,end FROM absence WHERE id='$getid'";
```

into this:

```
$requete = "SELECT id,title,start,end FROM absence WHERE id='" . $getid . "'";
```

You should also take a look at a tutorial related to [mysql injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php).

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle and I get the same result if in my events.php I write this : $requete = "SELECT id,title,start,end FROM absence WHERE id=37"; . It sounds like it doesn't gets the id from GET method so id=0 and nothing in my database has 0 in id so the calendar is empty.

Comment: @Geoffrey, if the result from your `events.php` is the same to what you've posted on your question, you are receiving the events in the json object. Look for the XHR response with Chrome developer tools (Network tab). That's the place where you make guarentee that fullcalendar is receiving the events. Did you add `allDay` ?

Comment: I've added allDayDefault: true, it has corrected a bug in the calendar when it was time to time writing a12 like at month december year 2014 in your jsfiddle. Thanks ! The XHR response with Chrome developer tools I'm not sure what you are talking about, "Inspect elements" ?

Comment: I’ve find the XHR with Firebug from Firefox. It shows this : http://localhost/planning/events.php?id=%27$getid%27&start=2015-02-01&end=2015-03-15&_=1425569410115 while trying to get the calendar on id 37. If I clic on this link it says this : Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$getid''' at line 1 ) 1

Comment: @Geoffrey Ok, we're getting somewhere. Take a look at my updated answer and correct the SQL query.

Comment: @Geoffrey I suppose you are using fullcalendar

Comment: @milz I have changed $requete to what you told me and it does the same things. Calendar empty and XHR says the same things.

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Yes, i'm using fullcalendar. Do you mean what i'm trying to do isn't possible with fullcalendar ?

Comment: @milz Thanks for the tutorial ! I will do that if we manage to solve the problem.

Comment: @Geoffrey, put a `die($getid)` before the query and let us know is the content of your variable. We know the problem lies with your query but I cant help you without knowing what is the query that you are executing. You need to debug on your side so we can have enought information to help you.

Comment: @Geoffrey in order for the events to be shown to the calendar you must use the renderEvent method http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/   take a look at it...I am using backbone to handle all these so I am not user how you can use it standalone

Comment: @milz die($getid) only do errors or write the id value of $getid on the screen (always correct).

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Thanks for the link but I don't understand how to use it. Can you explaine me how to use it with the code i've writed on my first post please ?

Comment: @Geoffrey there is another issue too...I saw the JSON response in your post...I noticed many object with the same ID...every object(which represents ab event) must have a unique ID...look into that first...

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou This is normal I did that. The id = the personnal id. It gets all events where personnel id = 37. I have id_absence who is unique. I know it may confuse.

Comment: @Geoffrey...it may be normal to you but not to fullcalendar...when fcal see s an ID in the response assumes that this is used to identify an event and as such every object must have a unique ID-and not other things.So you must use the ID for identifying the event and create another attribute for the personell ID...persID for example...try these and will see how things will go

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou and Geoffrey, please stop this discussion. The comments are not intended for discussions of this kind and this is way too long. Geoffrey: Your question is too broad and this discussion is going nowhere. You should read about a Stackoverflow's [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question. I'll vote to close this question as too broad unless you can edit your question to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example that we can replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...geofrey do what I suggest in the last comment...in other words redesign your database. I see you have placed an events source...so we are OK there.
Fix the database...I think that this should be OK